# CLI command to fetch detail for one package from Nuget

Tags: .net, nuget, command-line-interface

I need to get detail for one package from Nuget through CLI command. Below command returns me all packages which is unusable as it take alot of time to get executed.

nuget list -source http://nuget.org/api/v2

Answer (score 0):

From Visual Studio:

```
Find-Package -Source "http://nuget.org/api/v2" -Id "SomeName"
```

(or to be depreciated)

```
Get-Package -ListAvailable -Source "http://nuget.org/api/v2" -Filter *SomeName*
```

From Powershell v5:

```
Find-Package -Source "http://nuget.org/api/v2" -Name "SomeName"
```

You might be promted smth like

> Blockquote
>   nuget may be manually downloaded from https://oneget.org/Microsoft.PackageManagement.NuGetProvider-2.8.5.207.dll and installed.
>   Would you like PackageManagement to automatically download and install 'nuget' now?

In older versions of Powershell you might need to look into OneGet package manager (https://github.com/OneGet/oneget)

Comment: Thanks for help, any idea about how can I run these commands from Powershell ISE. I'm not using VS for this.

Comment: No..this doesn't seem to work for me. I need CLI command only as I'm running it from outside of VS.